# Prediction avoiding landmass

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, shortest-path, shapefile

I am working on a project where the following functions has to be implemented.

1. Predict the location of the ships (in maritime environment) into a future time (Can be done with Kalman filter, IMM filter and some other algorithms).
   Ships can be any part of the world.
2. Avoiding landmass during prediction
3. Shortest path along the shorelines

I am totally done with the first part which is predicting without considering the shoreline information. I have
problem with the functions 2 and 3.

Problem in function 2
At times, your predicted location can fall into the landmass area which is totally unacceptable.
I am using following coastal area shp file http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines
This file has converted XY values of the world shoreline data.
I have loaded this shp file into postgreSQL and used postgis to read it from the database.

So my idea is to go through all the polygons (shoreline defined based on polygons)  and checking whether the line connecting the present location and the predicted location 
crosses the polygon. If it crosses, that means we have to find the where the ship intercept the shoreline first.
So if I follow this approach going through all the polygons, it is going to take time forever. (It has around 62000 polygons with each of them has 1000's of
points). So any advice on this? I thought about initially dividing the worldmap into hierachical areas (Level 1 : 10 polygons, Level 2: Each polygon has 10 polygons inside).
But I am not sure how to divide the world map with the above shp file into the level of polygons I require.
Or any functionality of postgis helpful for this? or any other libraries for this purpose. I believe this kind of functionality should be available already. But I could not
able to figure it out sofar.

Function 3
Since now we know where does the ship intercept the shoreline first, we can predict it along the shoreline using the shortest path algorithm given we know
the destination information. But to do this, you need to divide the above shoreline map into grids so the shortest path can be used.
So how can you make grids based on this along the shorelines? I am not doing image processing here. What I have is this shp file now. Any advice is appreciated.
or should I go with some image processing approach and make the grid shorelines. if so please provide some links.

Comment: Consider posting this question to gis.stackexchange.com.  There are many GIS experts there that could provide good approaches for your problem.  Regarding function 2, you should use a spatial index.  See http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/indexing.html

Comment: Thanks Ireeder. I have posted there too, but still no answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, PostGIS is pretty fast, and with the proper indexes, as long as you keep your polygons reasonably small, you should be able to make up for the number of them with good indexing and overlapping operator support (overlapping polygons can use `GIST` and `GIN` indexes, with the latter performing better than the former for reads and worse for writes).

62000 polygons globally is nothing.  Write back when you are having to check more than a few thousand whose bounding boxes overlap with your line....

For the third problem, you are going one direction, right?  I am wondering how hard it would be to write a `tangent(point, vector, polygon)` function which would return the closest tangent to a polygon along a certain vector (a vector could be represented by a `(point, point)` tuple).  If you were to combine this with KNN searches, you ought to be able to plot a course using a `WITH RECURSIVE` query.